# How to temporarily mute a conversation in messages on macOS

Tags: mac, messages

What I am looking for is the corresponding functionality that I have on my iPhone, where I can mute a conversation for an hour, or the rest of the day.

I thought this would be obvious, but when I google it only see solutions for how I mute the conversation indefinitely.

To start with I would think that when I select mute for today on my iPhone, this would have effect on the notifications on my mac as well, but to my surprise it doesn't.

So how do I get the same effect on the notifications for my mac without having to mute it indefinitely?